# RabbitMQ command rabbitmqctl start_app not working in Windows

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

I want to run RabbitMQ locally in my Windows system. I have installed Erlang and then RabbitMQ. RabbitMQ is installed successfully. I want to use the management UI of RabbitMQ by accessing http://localhost:15672/ but I am not able to open it. Below is the error screenshot.
[Not able to access http://localhost:15672/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuHVm.png) 
I believe it could be either for port blockage by firewall or because RabbitMQ node is not running properly. When I ran `rabbitmqctl start_app` it was not successful. So I believe the issue resides with RabbitMQ node running.

I have installed Erlang and then RabbitMQ in Windows. In Services I can see RabbitMQ service running.I ran following commands

- `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`
- `rabbitmq-server start`
- `rabbitmqctl start_app` - This is where it failed but not showing any error in RabbitMQ cmd. Screenshot is attached.
  [Error while running RabbitMQ command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCocK.png)

Has anybody come across this kind of issue before? Please suggest.

Comment: RabbitMQ 3.8 is no longer supported. If you would like to receive assistance, you need to be more precise in how you report your issue. Let us know _exactly_ what you installed (Erlang and RabbitMQ), and _how_ you installed it. Stack Overflow is not a good place to diagnose issues so I suggest using this - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions